# End Regex pattern on first occurrence in multiline

Tags: regex

Hello have have this string

```
  <20170503-18:19:09, FIXT.1.1:BANZAI->EXEC, event> (Initiated logon request)
  <20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, incoming> (8=FIX.4.4☺9=67☺35=A☺
  34=177☺49=EXEC☺52=20170503-18:19:09.298☺56=BANZAI☺98=0☺108=30☺10=092☺)
  <20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, event> 
  (Received logon) fdsfhffghgfhgjgf  177☺49=EXEC☺52=20170503-18:19:09.298☺
  56=BANZAI☺98 (Received logon) more stuff after this....
```

I want to find if after keyword "Initiated logon request" there is a following response "Received logon" when I write my regex pattern like this to accommodate for multi-line and any character in between

```
 Initiated logon request.*[\S\s]*Received logon
```

I get everything up the the last keyword in the string 
result

```
  Initiated logon request)
  <20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, incoming> (8=FIX.4.4☺9=67☺35=A☺
  34=177☺49=EXEC☺52=20170503-18:19:09.298☺56=BANZAI☺98=0☺108=30☺10=092☺)
  <20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, event> 
  (Received logon) fdsfhffghgfhgjgf  177☺49=EXEC☺52=20170503-18:19:09.298☺
  56=BANZAI☺98 (Received logon
```

what I want to do is to stop the regex when first keyword is found,

```
  Initiated logon request)
  <20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, incoming> (8=FIX.4.4☺9=67☺35=A☺
  34=177☺49=EXEC☺52=20170503-18:19:09.298☺56=BANZAI☺98=0☺108=30☺10=092☺)
  <20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, event> 
  (Received logon
```

Is there a way to do this thank you for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use lookahead positive assertion `(?=...)` and non-greedy quantifier `*?`:

```
Initiated logon request[\S\s]*?(?=\(Received logon\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/TSfjiS/3

Comment: thank you that was I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To get only upto first match of 'Received logon', use this:

```
Initiated logon request((?!Received logon)[\s\S])*Received logon
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/B8aNrO/1)

Output:

```
Initiated logon request)
<20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, incoming> (8=FIX.4.4☺9=67☺35=A☺
34=177☺49=EXEC☺52=20170503-18:19:09.298☺56=BANZAI☺98=0☺108=30☺10=092☺)
<20170503-18:19:09, FIX.4.4:BANZAI->EXEC, event> 
(Received logon
```

Comment: Read ["When Not to Use this Technique" section here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) to understand that your suggested solution is not good to use here.

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense. No point using an expensive solution when a lazy quantifier is more than enough! Thank you @WiktorStribiżew :)